# Iterating over associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$pedidos` which I fill by:

```
$pedido[$nombreProducto['nombre']] = $cantidad;
```

So, when U try to iterate over it with this loop:

```
foreach ($pedidos as $key => $value) {
    echo $key."-->".$value;
}
```

I'm getting the error log message:

> *Invalid argument supplied for foreach()*

How should I iterate over it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your array is called `$pedido` change the for each with this:

```
foreach ($pedido as $key => $value) {
    echo $key."-->".$value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In foreach you have `$pedidos`, but you are filling array `$pedido`